# Why does inserting way after the end of a list work in Python?

Tags: python, list

I thought that

```
a = []
a.insert(42, "the answer")
```

would raise an exception (perhaps IndexError), but it doesn't. Both Python 2.7 and 3.6 create a list with one element at index 0.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) says

> **`list.insert(i, x)`**
>
> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is **the index of the element before which to insert**, so `a.insert(0, x)` inserts
>   at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a), x)` is equivalent to
>   `a.append(x)`.

And apparently `a.insert(i, x)` with `i>len(a)` is also equivalent to `a.append(x)`. Is this intended or at least documented? I could not find anything yet.